How can I repair a cabinet hinge torn from the frame?
Someone fell and landed on an open bathroom vanity door.  It ripped the upper hinge from the side of the cabinet, and splintering the wood.  Using the same 3/4" screw would not work as the back side of the cabinet was "blown out".
The outside face was not damaged so all the repair can be done on the inside of the cabinet.  How would you go about it?
The damage was on the cabinet, not the door side.


Can you please provide some photos of the damage?

If the blown out area was just a bit more than the hinge, should be able to move the hinge down(or up) to good wood.  The blown out area can then be filled in with wood filler or similar and painted.  Pictures would help give better answers, type of door, hinge design.

photos of the cabinet from farther away would be better.

This is so close (and fuzzy) that I'm not sure what I'm looking at in the overall scene. Please back up a bit and get good focus and lighting. Also show us the hinge, as I requested earlier.

You probably need a cabinet repair plate.
This allows the installation of hidden hinges into damaged cabinets.
Unfortunately these work only on full face cabinet and not those with a face frame.

This seems like a great suggestion if the damage was on the door side.

Check ALL the info on the repair plates...they can be used on the door and the cabinet.
